# Why the tail queue in the OpenBSD <sys/queue.h> uses the pointer to pointer?

Tags: c, pointers

```
#define TAILQ_ENTRY(type)                       \
struct {                                \
    struct type *tqe_next;  /* next element */          \
    struct type **tqe_prev; /* address of previous next element */  \
}
```

The code as shown above, why it uses the `struct type **tqe_prev`, is there something better than `struct type *tqe_prev` ?

Comment: Reading the comment tells me that `tqe_prev` is a pointer the previous nodes `tqe_next` member. So it's pointing to another pointer.

Answer (score 1):

A reason is the `head` of the list. With the pointer to pointer approach, a node can always be removed with:

```
*tqe_prev = tqe_next;
if(tqe_next) tqe_next->tqe_prev = tqe_prev;
```

even when it is the first node.

The entire queue is usually accessed by `head` pointer that points to the first node, or `null` when the queue is empty, for example:

```
struct type* head;
```

The first node's `tqe_prev` points to this `head` pointer. That's why the above deletion code can also remove the first node from the queue. The code has access to the pointer that points to the node to be deleted, and can thus make it point to the next node. If the node was the only one left in the queue, `head` will be set to `null` when it's deleted.

This would not be possible if it was a simple pointer like `tqe_next`.